# Handle php array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I'm fetching a php array in js.

The php array name is "data" , the vra_dump($data) is:

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(3) { ["destinationid"]=> string(4) "d001" ["name"]=> string(9) "Kathmandu" ["countdest"]=> int(4) } [1]=> array(3) { ["destinationid"]=> string(4) "d002" ["name"]=> string(6) "Meerut" ["countdest"]=> int(4) } [2]=> array(3) { ["destinationid"]=> string(4) "d003" ["name"]=> string(9) "New Delhi" ["countdest"]=> int(4) } [3]=> array(3) { ["destinationid"]=> string(4) "d004" ["name"]=> string(7) "Gurgaon" ["countdest"]=> int(4) } }
```

The result is the required one.

Now, when I send this array in ajax request response, when I alert the array as alert(data);

The following output is:

[image: array reslu in alert]

How should I access this array in js?

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript.

```
  var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
  $.each(parsed, function(index, value){
   console.log(index + value); //I prefer this to inspect the data
   alert(value['name']);
  });
```

Comment: Hey I got my data in console log as:

[Object { destinationid="d001",  name="Kathmandu",  countdest=4}, Object { destinationid="d002",  name="Meerut",  countdest=4}, Object { destinationid="d003",  name="New Delhi",  countdest=4}, Object { destinationid="d004",  name="Gurgaon",  countdest=4}]

How to access the array elements?

Comment: In console I can access my elements as parsed[0] or any index. But its not working on an alert.

Comment: Yes. It's not working because alert only handles specific data.

Comment: Don't use alert, use console.log

Answer (score 0):

it looks you do not use json to send and receive
[see this example](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/multidim-arrays.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use echo json_encode($data) in your PHP and you get a regular object in JavaScript AJAX success, so you can use like: data[0].destinationid, and you can use it in an $.each() and so on...

Answer (score -1):

You need to `json_encode` the PHP array, and the write it to a JS variable.

```
<script>
    var data = '<?php json_encode($data) ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

This is the error I got

Comment: Do not write PHP in your JavaScript!

Comment: @MartinJoó  There are many situations when parsing PHP inside JS is perfectly acceptable.  I was presuming that $data existed in PHP first, then needed to be accessed by JS to be submitted via AJAX.  I'm happy to be wrong, but your comment is a little 'knife and fork'

Comment: Okay, sorry. In my point of view, there is no situation when I should write PHP in JS. Just send an AJAX, and get your result from the server, that's it. You just do an echo json_encode($data); in PHP and get a nice JS object in AJAX success(data) where data gonna be the json formatted JS object that contains your data, that comes from PHP $data.